# Limit using/typedef to class scope

Tags: c++, windows, templates

I need to store a function prototype inside of a class somehow, but it automatically becomes a global when I try to do so.

The prototype is given trough a template, but I cannot use it straight out of there as I use it inside of thread member function which has to be static (Because otherwise, I break the callback prototype because of the `this` pointer).

I cannot have it go global, as I would need to run multiple instances of the class and the prototypes would get jumbled up.

Is there a way to do this?

```
template<class proto>
class cl
{
private:
    using m_proto = proto;
    void* addr;
public:
    static void thread(void* p)
    {
        // p receives a pointer to the current class
        cl* clp = (cl*)p;
        ((m_proto)clp->addr)();
    }
};
```

Comment: If you can migrate to [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread), all of your problems will just... go away. You can run a member function without any `void*`s, `static` methods, or any of the ick you seem to be struggling with. See the linked documentation for examples.

Comment: That's true, but I know there's a way I can do it myself, just don't know how (besides making a wrapper for threads myself, which I will do if I cannot figure this out)

Comment: Understood. I just find it helpful to lead with the easy way in case an asker is unaware of it.

Comment: I'm glad you didn't take it the wrong way. Usually when I reject a user's idea here they take it personally. I'm more inclined to use it now, not going to lie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
void (*addr)();
```

This declares `addr` as a member variable of type `void (*)()`.

You can make it more readable by using.

```
using my_ptr_type = void (*)();
my_ptr_type addr;
```

Comment: I just realized I mistakenly believed I would be passing parameters to my function so I would need to handle different prototypes, but you made me realize they would all absolutely have to be void with no parameters in my case. Thanks, man.